# Do holders of India e-tourist visas get a visa in the passport on arrival?

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

I'm curious as to the following: when applying for and obtaining an Indian e-Tourist visa, do you actually get a visa in your passport at the Airport, or only an entry stamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you receive an e-Tourist Visa then [this will be e-mailed to you](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html). You are expected to print it out, carry it with you, and show it at airline check-in and at immigration. No visa sticker will be placed in your passport.

On arrival in India you will get an entry stamp, the same as everyone else.

Note that the e-TV only grants a single entry good for 30 days stay. If you need another entry, you can apply for another e-TV later; if you need a longer duration or multiple entries, consider applying for a regular visa instead.